# define the API following the OpenAPI standard and implement the client and service in the Ballerina language?

Tags: ballerina

The problem centers on developing a Restful API for effectively managing staff, their offices, and
allocated courses within the Faculty of Computing and Informatics. These offices can
accommodate multiple lecturers. A lecturer is characterized by essential attributes, including a
staff number, office number, staff name, title, and a list of the courses they are teaching.
Additionally, a course is characterized by specific details such as the course name, course code,
and NQF (National Qualifications Framework) level.
The API should include the following functionalities:
• Add a new lecturer
• Retrieve a list of all lecturers within the faculty.
• Update an existing lecturer's information.
• Retrieve the details of a specific lecturer by their staff number.
• Delete a lecturer's record by their staff number.
• Retrieve all the lecturers that teach a certain course.
• Retrieve all the lecturers that sit in the same office.
Note that the staff number should serve as a unique identifier for a lecturer.
Your task is to define the API following the OpenAPI standard and implement the client and
service in the Ballerina language.
Deliverables:
• OpenAPI specification in YAML or JSON format.(15 marks)
• Client Implementation in a Ballerina that effectively interacts with the designed API.(10
marks)
• Service Implementation (25 Marks)

Answer (score 0):

For guidance on writing the OpenAPI specification according to your requirements, refer to the following documents:[Swagger Basic Structure](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/basic-structure/), [Swagger Specification](https://swagger.io/specification/)

To generate the necessary Ballerina code from your OpenAPI specification using the Ballerina OpenAPI tool, use the following command inside your Ballerina package:

`bal openapi -i <input openapi file>`

Executing this command will generate four Ballerina source files: **client.bal**, **service.bal**, **utils.bal** and **types.bal**. These files provide the foundation for your Ballerina project.

In **service.bal**, you will need to implement the service logic within the service skeleton body. This is where you define the behaviour of your API endpoints, including how they handle incoming requests and produce responses. Customize the service logic according to your specific application requirements.

With these generated files, you can kickstart your Ballerina project and build upon them to create a fully functional API based on your OpenAPI specification.

For more information on the Ballerina OpenAPI tool, please visit the [Ballerina OpenAPI Tool documentation](https://ballerina.io/learn/openapi-tool/). You can also explore the Ballerina language further on the [Ballerina Language website](https://ballerina.io/).